# how to make web application as hybrid mobile app

Tags: mobile, kendo-ui

There are several ways to build mobile app like pure html5, native app, hybrid app.

**So my question is**: in hybrid app mode, which container is good for Kendo UI/Pure Html+JQuery. (to make the question clear, what I mean is: Build a web on Kendo UI core(html + Jquery), which tools can be used to make the web install on iphone/andorid phone?)

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by Tool ?

Comment: 'Packaging (native)
Kendo UI apps will require external tools for packaging purposes.'


what external tools can be used? (both commercial and free tools)

Comment: @suraj mahajan I did some study, and find phonegap maybe work

Comment: Nice. Phonegap is best framework. Nice choice :)